# Replace with a single backslash in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, replace, latex

I'm creating a latex templating system using Node.js. As part of this system, I need to escape any characters with special meanings by prefixing them with a backslash.

I've read that a double-backslash is used to insert a literal backslash:

```
> var input = "hello & 100%"
> input.replace(/([&%$#_{}])/g, "\\$1")
'hello \\& 100\\%'
```

Nope. I've also read that because it's inside a string, I need to double-escape the backslash:

```
> input.replace(/([&%$#_{}])/g, "\\\\$1")
'hello \\\\& 100\\\\%'
```

Nope. And using just one backslash doesn't do it either:

```
> input.replace(/([&%$#_{}])/g, "\$1")
'hello & 100%'
```

So how am I supposed to insert a single backslash using `replace()`?

Comment: The output of the first should be `hello \& 100\%` (http://jsfiddle.net/251obLmx/) if you see \\ is it an artifact of the console trying to be helpful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the first method is correct and works. Two backslash is indeed used to make a single backslash.

```
console.log("hello & 100%".replace(/([&%$#_{}])/g, "\\$1")); // "hello \& 100\%"
```

If `console.log` is giving you some trouble, which it shouldn't, try `alert`.
Also you need to use the return value which you aren't doing.

Comment: I never suspected that the raw output from the replace command would be extra escaped! You're right, as long as I wrap the whole thing in console.log() it outputs correctly. Thanks!